# How to write SELF JOIN on the same table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, self-join

### I have a table named "comment",  like bellow :

c_id | c_action | r_c_id
-----------------------------
1    | post     | NULL 
2    | post     | NULL 
3    | post     | NULL 
4    | post     | NULL 
5    | reply    | 1    
6    | reply    | 1   
7    | reply    | 3    
8    | reply    | 3   
9    | reply    | 3  
10   | reply    | 4

-----------------------------------

I want to all 'post' result with a extra column replies, where in replies column
count all reply where c_id = r_c_id, something like bellow:

c_id | c_action | r_c_id | replies
-----------------------------------
1    | post     | NULL   | 2 
2    | post     | NULL   | 0 
3    | post     | NULL   | 4 
4    | post     | NULL   | 1

---

Comment: you mean you have 2 tables with a column existind in both (like an ID" column) ? then just use `join` : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: Posts need to be self-containing - include all necessary info directly in itself

Comment: Please  - no pictures. Write the data in formatted code blocks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple SELF JOIN to the same table with condition connecting c_id with rep_c_id:

```
SELECT
  t1.c_id, 
  t1.c_action,
  t1.rep_c_id,
  COUNT(t2.c_id) AS replies
FROM
  tablename t1
  LEFT JOIN tablename t2 ON t1.c_id = t2.rep_c_id
WHERE
  t1.c_action = 'post'
GROUP BY t1.c_id, t1.c_action, t1.rep_c_id
```

Comment: It was my first version.I don't know what got me into changing this. I was somewhat afraid it wouldn't :o Thanks.